# Selenium Python getting specific text in data-sort

Tags: python, html, selenium

a In a HTML page there is this line:

```
<td data-sort="funny" class="coin-name tw-text-right" style="min-width: 60px;">
```

and I can find it by using this XPATH:

```
//tbody/tr/td[5]
```

But I only interesting to put in a variable the "funny". Keep in mind that the word "funny" is changing all the time so I need to find it and push it to variable but how do I extract this changing text?

Thank you for helping ;-)

Comment: get thge element and then get the attribute , cannot say how to get the element without seeing other elements parent object etc

Comment: @PDHide Is the SQAT flag queue empty :)

Comment: @PDHide take a look at https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added how do I extract the chain name? What ever I tried the variable left empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work 100% but here is one potential solution:

1. If you open up that  tag you will find out that the first child's second child(Refer to image in solution) has a unique `id` attribute.
2. Then, you can use that unique attribute and work your way up to the parent  tag with "data-sort attribute" using **Child-to-Parent** Traversing using Xpath. [Refer to the image it basically explains the same approach written above][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dc2k.png

3.Once you uniquely identify the `td` tag you can then use `getAttribute()` and store its value.

Comment: I can't get it work but maybe I don't know how, can you look at the link  coingecko.com/en/coins/recently_added and look at the XPATH //tbody/tr/td[5] and help me retrieve the blockchain name?